# Rails Create an object Array of my class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Example java code is below if I have a class Movie
In java I will create its array by writing below code
    Movie[] a = new Movie[4];

but how I can do it in rails So that when I check it on the console

```
#> a.type
#> "Movie"
```

Reather than

```
#> ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Comment: Please learn how to use SO formatting, don't use HTML tags again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create a class by inherited from Array like below,

```
class MyArray < Array
 #Add you custom methods
end

my_array = MyArray.new([1,2,3,4,5]) or

my_array = MyArray.new
my_array[0] = 1
my_array[1] = 2
```

That enough for basic customization of array data structure.

Comment: Movie is my model class

Answer (score 1):

Literal translation would be

```
a = (1..4).map { Movie.new }
```

or (in Rails)

```
a = (1..4).map { Movie.create! }
```

but you normally shouldn't need to do it, since unlike in Java, you don't have limited-size arrays in Ruby.

Also, the type of that would then be `Array` (or rather its class; basic Ruby objects don't have `type`); the type of an *element* of that, `a[0]` for example, would be a `Movie`.

In the end, not quite sure what you're asking here...